# Possible Outcomes in a Tournament

Tags: probability, combinations

Two players A and B are to play badminton. The first person to win 2 games in a row or who wins a total of 3 games wins. How many possible outcomes are there in the tournament? Enumerate all possible outcomes.

Eg: (let w=won, l=lost) Possible outcomes={ww, wlww, wlwlw, wlwllw, wllww, wllwlw, wlllww, wllllww, wllllwlw, wlllllww,...} Its endless but the question requires all outcomes to be enumerated. Please help.

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck. Add that to your question. Btw, it is not a big job to go along all possibilities. If you do that then you will gain understanding.

Comment: I tried to enumerate all possible outcomes but it seems endless. Suppose you won the first game and you lost the succeeding games, the premise "2 games in a row or a total of 3 games won" could be endless. Please help.

Comment: As I said: *add to your question* (not a comment). Especially showing your own efforts will prevent people to downvote your question.

Comment: Eg: (let w=won, l=lost) Possible outcomes={ww, wlww, wlwlw, wlwllw, wllww, wllwlw, wlllww, wllllww, wllllwlw, wlllllww,...} Its endless but the question requires all outcomes to be enumerated.

Comment: By wlwlw three games are won. So the match is over, right?

Comment: Yes. But as long as the player encounters loss, the possible outcome would continue to increase. And the requirement is to enumerate 'all' possible outcomes. How could that be?

Comment: Maybe I have a blind spot, but I think that: $AA$, $BAA$, $ABAA$,$BABAA$ and $ABABA$ are all the games won by $A$. Interchanging $A$ and $B$ gives the games won by $B$. So an enumeration of $10$, not endless.

Comment: genius! i suggest you move your comment as answer. that makes sense! thanks for your help!! ^_^

Comment: Glad to help. I (still) cannot resist the temptation and followed your suggestion. ;) Genius? Not very realistic, but I will show this compliment to my daughter. She might believe it.

Comment: she must believe! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AA$ , $BAA$ , $ABAA$ ,$BABAA$  and $ABABA$  represent all the games won by $A$ .

Interchanging $A$  and $B$  gives the games won by $B$ .

An enumeration of $10$ possibilities.